# Simple logic/algebra question using inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logic

Say $b$ is less than $c$, which is less than $d$ but $2c$ is greater than $b+d$.

Then between $\frac{d-b}{2}$ and $d-c$, which one is greater?

Between $d-b$ and $\frac{d-c}{2}$, which one is greater?

Comment: hi lulu. the question is written on the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, we have $b < c$, $c < d$, and $b + d < 2c$.

$$\begin{align}
2c & > b + d\\
-b &> d - 2c\\
d - b &> 2d - 2c\\
\frac{d-b}{2} &> d - c\\
\end{align}$$

That answers the first question.  Starting with that answer,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d - b}{2} &> d - c\\
\frac{d - b}{4} &> \frac{d - c}{2}\\
\text{Because we know $d > c > b$ ,  $\frac{3(d - b)}{4} > 0$, }\\
d - b &> \frac{d-c}{2}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d-b}{2}>d-c$$ because it's
$$d-b>2d-2c$$ or
$$2c>d+b,$$
which is given.

For the second problem we have:
$$2c>b+d>b+c,$$
which says
$$c>b.$$

Thus, $$d+c>2c>2b,$$
which gives $$d+c>2b,$$
which is
$$d-b>\frac{d-c}{2}.$$
Done!